# Adding Multiple View Controllers to ViewController.swift From Storyboard UI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I have created several view controllers that I wish to now add tap actions to in my Main.storyboard, but they are not connected to the ViewController.swift.  I am trying to connect the ViewControllers via the control-click-drag-to-swift-file method, but the object does not appear in the swift file. Is there a way to simply import your entire storyboard with all the ViewControllers into the swift file so you can start coding?

Thank you.

Comment: You need a different ViewController class for each view controller in the storyboard. You cannot connect all the view controllers to one class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have multiple view controllers all with the same class "ViewController" that you want to duplicate and edit all the same way? You have to label each class differently or else the system crashes its like having twins and naming them all the same name and getting confused why they dont know which one you are talking to.